# How to check if a symlink target matches a specific path?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, symlink

I'm creating a bash script to check if a symlink target matches a specific path so, in case it doesn't match, script removes the symlink. I've tried with `readlink`:

```
#!/bin/env bash

target_path=$HOME/Code/slate/.slate.js

if [ `readlink $HOME/.slate.js` == "$target_path" ]; then
    rm -rf "$HOME/.slate.js"
fi
```

but it doesn't work:

```
%source test
test:5: = not found
```

Comment: **readlink $HOME/.slate.js** might not return exactly the same as **$target_path** it might return something like **Code/slate/.slate.js** which is different from $target_path

Comment: Does `$HOME` have a space in it, perchance?

Comment: echo both of them to checking actualy they are equal

Comment: `test` is probably not a good name for a shell script, as it's already a shell built-in and a binary in `/bin` (or `/usr/bin`)...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use double quotes as follow when you compare strings (and yes, the output of `readlink $HOME/.slate.js` is a string):

```
[ "$(readlink $HOME/.slate.js)" = "$target_path" ]
```

Answer (score 7):

In case `$target_path` does not match the link text exactly, you can check that they are, in fact equivalent (regardless of name). But since a hardlink is preferable you might want to check that case, too (see below).

A more generic solution is:

```
[ "$(readlink $HOME/.slate.js)" -ef "$target_path" ]
```

Or, as in your example:

```
target_path=$HOME/Code/slate/.slate.js

if [ "`readlink $HOME/.slate.js`" -ef "$target_path" ]; then
    rm -rf "$HOME/.slate.js"
fi
```

But that all assumes that your `$HOME/.slate.js` is a symbolic link. If it is a hard link (which is preferable, when possible), then it is simpler:

```
 … [ "$HOME/.slate.js" -ef "$target_path" ] …
```

Maybe something like (check whether it is a symlink, if so, then check that link matches target; otherwise check whether the files same—either a hard link or actually the same file):

```
 … [ \( -L "$HOME/.slate.js" -a "`readlink $HOME/.slate.js`" -ef "$target_path" \) \
     -o \( "$HOME/.slate.js" -ef "$target_path" \) ] …
```

You should also check whether the file is, in fact, the same file (and not a hard link), otherwise you will delete the one and only copy.